# I have added profile activity, then added a dynamic image profile and username. After i did that, the navigation buttons are not working at all

Tags: android

## here is my java code

that is the java code, I have added navigation profile activity then run it after retrieving the image and user name from the firebase. the navigation buttons are no more clickable

```
public class OwnerDrawer extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private FirebaseAuth OwnerAuth;
    private DatabaseReference OwnerRef;
    private CircleImageView OwnNavProfileImge;
    private TextView OwnNavProfileName;
    String currentUserID;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_owner_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        OwnerAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        OwnerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        currentUserID = OwnerAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        //for the navigation drawer button to open and close
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);



        View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_owner_drawer);
        OwnNavProfileName = (TextView)navView.findViewById(R.id.NavOwnerUserName);
        OwnNavProfileImge = (CircleImageView)navView.findViewById(R.id.NavOwnerProfileImage);

        OwnerRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())                {
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("fullname"))
                    {
                        String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                        OwnNavProfileName.setText(fullname);
                    }
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimage"))
                    {
                        String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                        Picasso.with(OwnerDrawer.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(OwnNavProfileImge);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(OwnerDrawer.this, "Profile name does not exist...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser =  OwnerAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser == null)
        {
            SendUserTologinActivity();
        }
        else
        {
            CheckUserExistence();
        }
    }
    // to see if the user validation and his authenticated so if not, the user will be send to the setup activity.
    private void CheckUserExistence()
    {
        final String current_user_id = OwnerAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        OwnerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public      void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id))
                {
                    SendUserToSetupActivity();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void SendUserToSetupActivity()
    {
        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(OwnerDrawer.this, OwnerSetup.class);
        setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(setupIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void SendUserTologinActivity() {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(OwnerDrawer.this,OwnerLogin.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    // To open the menu button


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_Home) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Profile) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Posting_Cars) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Post Cars", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Chat) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Chat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Edit_profile) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Edit Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if (id == R.id.nav_Logout) {
            OwnerAuth.signOut();
            SendUserTologinActivity();
            Toast.makeText(OwnerDrawer.this, "Logged Out Successfull...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: any solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

To receive callbacks when the user taps a list item in the drawer,  implement the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` and attach it to your NavigationView by calling `setNavigationItemSelectedListener()`.

You need to attach the navigationView to listener

`navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`

Hope this helps.